Form field cuts out when used below Stepper. Angular 18
So I'm trying to create a stepper with some form fields in it, everything checks out but the form fields all get cut out by the stepper labels no matter how much margin I give them or if I set overflow to visible!
Evidence of the cutout of the input of the form field
As to my code, here is the HTML template for my component:
<div class="stepper-container">
  <mat-horizontal-stepper linear #stepper>
    <mat-step label="Dirección" [stepControl]="addressForm">
      <form [formGroup]="addressForm">
        <div>
          <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>Address</mat-label>
            <input matInput formControlName="address" />
            <mat-error *ngIf="addressControl?.invalid"
              >Dirección requerida</mat-error
            >
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="stepper.next()">
            Siguiente
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </mat-step>

    <mat-step label="Información del Vehículo" [stepControl]="vehicleForm">
      <form [formGroup]="vehicleForm">
        <div class="step-content">
          <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>Vehicle Info</mat-label>
            <input matInput formControlName="vehicleInfo" />
            <mat-error *ngIf="vehicleForm.get('vehicleInfo')?.invalid">
              Información del vehículo requerida
            </mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
        <div class="step-content">
          <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>Seleccione sus servicios</mat-label>
            <input matInput formControlName="services" />
            <mat-error *ngIf="vehicleForm.get('services')?.invalid">
              Debe seleccionar al menos un servicio
            </mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="stepper.next()">
            Siguiente
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </mat-step>

    <mat-step>
      <ng-template matStepLabel>Resumen</ng-template>
      <p>Dirección: {{ addressForm.value.address }}</p>
      <p>Información del Vehículo: {{ vehicleForm.value.vehicleInfo }}</p>
      <p>Servicios Seleccionados: {{ vehicleForm.value.services.join(", ") }}</p>
      <p>Precio total: {{ totalPrice | currency }}</p>
      <div>
        <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="stepper.next()">
          Siguiente
        </button>
      </div>
    </mat-step>

    <!-- Phase 4: Checkout -->
    <mat-step>
      <ng-template matStepLabel>Pago</ng-template>
      <p>Proceder a pagar</p>
      <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="checkout()">
        Pago
      </button>
    </mat-step>
  </mat-horizontal-stepper>
</div>

I have tried amplifying the margin for the form field and setting the overflow to visible in both form field and stepper but all it lead to was this weird looking interaction where the form field moves but the cutout is still there for some reason.
Code used:
mat-form-field {
    width: 100%; /* Asegurar que los campos del formulario ocupen todo el ancho disponible */
    margin-top: 100px; /* Add top margin to separate form fields from stepper labels */
    display: block; /* Asegurar que los campos del formulario se muestren como elementos de bloque */
    overflow: visible; /* Asegurar que el desbordamiento sea visible */
}

Result:
Evidence of cutout still being there with a lot of space

please create a stackblitz.

We believe the issue was with the <div class="stepper-container"> and <mat-horizontal-stepper> tags, so we removed them.
After removing these lines, we were able to get the desired output using the following sample code:
<mat-stepper [linear]="isLinear" #stepper>
  <mat-step label="Dirección" [stepControl]="secondFormGroup">
    <form [formGroup]="secondFormGroup">
      <div>
        <mat-form-field>
          <mat-label>Address</mat-label>
          <input matInput formControlName="secondCtrl" />
          <mat-error>Dirección requerida</mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button mat-raised-button color="primary">
          Siguiente
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </mat-step>
</mat-stepper>

